# Google Cloud Dataflow fix zero based indexing and one based index

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

My team and I are starting to use Google Cloud Dataflow to run our jobs remotely and not locally on our computers. We started from the julian example set in Python to make sure that a deployment was working successfully.

It did complete on Google Cloud Dataflow even though it took longer than it did on my local machine.

The issue we have is they used zero based indexing and one based indexing in the same file name which did not make sense to us.

[image]

We think ending at 00008-of-00008 or 00009-of-00009 make more sense than ending at 00008-of-00009. Is there anyway we can fix this so that the left and right side numbers could match?

Comment: As a note on your comment, small jobs can take longer on GCP than on a local run because VMs need to be reserved and started up.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks! We're glad to hear this and were hoping that smaller jobs were not taking advantage of things like parallelization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using The `0000X-of-0000Y` format, Beam tries to do an `index-of-count`. The number in the right is the total number of shards, while the number on the left is a zero-based index.

Changing this behavior is not currently supported (easily) by the sinks in Apache Beam. To add it yourself, you'd have to modify the code in Apache Beam (specifically, [around here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L698)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for finding that for us Pablo! We were hoping for an easy solution that didn't involve editing Apache Beam code so we could also easily stay up-to-date with their updates.